# Python: Reading bytes from a file and converting it to the needed type

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I am trying to implement a code which reads the bytes from a file and computes the histogram of the byte count frequencies:

I am using this code to read from a file and writing to a csv file:

```
block_size = int(block_size)
data_block = data[:block_size]
encoded_data_block = base64.b64encode(data_block).decode("utf-8")
csv_writer.writerow([encoded_data_block, label])
```

later on, I am trying to read from the csv file to compute the byte count:

for example, one of the rows in my csv file looks something like this:

```
b'a2pUuzNscSX+UaAz9KAMtls+OeN08DtLa4WYri76IouKLNp+iXaKntSqKBQZLqIdG/xt4GWiXD08nI
```

in an example dataset and code that i am referring to, the rows of the csv file are looking like this:

```
b'x\x9c\x9c\xbd\xcb\x8e\x1cW\x96-8\xe7W\x18\x1c(\x88\x04<\x02\x0c\xea\x9d\x1aQ$\xf5*QR\x89\xcc\xd2\xbdU\xa8\x81\xb9\xdb\xf1p\x13\xcd\xcd<\xed\x11A\xd7(q\xd1
```

i want my dataset rows also to be like above, so that i can test my code against theirs. can anyone please help in how can i get my data to be of the above format?

Comment: Are you reading data as bytes or as string?

Comment: @MilosStojanovic, as string, as seen from the below code:
block_size = int(block_size)
data_block = data[:block_size]

the dataset that i am referring to, they are also reading as string and then they are using eval() to convert to byte type before computing the histogram
but when i am trying to use "eval()" on my dataset, i am getting "Invalid binary literal"

Comment: `encoded_data_block = repr(data_block)`

Comment: For safety reasons, I would also recommend to use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval` here.

Comment: Hi @MichaelButscher, thanks for the reply.issue is am not able to use "eval()" since am getting "invalid binary literal". i want my dataset to be of this format: "b'x\x9c\x9c\xbd\xcb\x8e\x1cW\x96-8\xe"..currently i am using bytes() to convert string to bytes

Comment: My first comment should help to solve this issue. The second is just an additional recommendation.

Comment: oh ok, thanks. let me try that

Comment: yeah it works. thanks @MichaelButscher.. so repr() converts the data into the hex-string?

Comment: If possible, it converts it to a representation which can be used as **literal** in Python code and therefore can be processed by `eval`.